# Blackberry cod and alx Name?

Tags: blackberry

My app name is "TheTestApp". My requirement is my app name should be like this "Test's app". Is it possible? When install on device it should show "Test's app". How to achieve this in Blackberry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your BlackBerry_App_Descriptor and change the Title. If you're using an internationalization bundle change whatever String "Title ID" is pointing to

Comment: This changes the app name, but still the cod & alx file have the old names

Comment: The OP was asking how to change the app title, not the COD name (contrary to the title of the question)

Comment: OK, I added an extra piece of info, as answer, to help those who are searching and met the title "Blackberry cod and alx Name?" ... Thanks

Comment: Always helpful in case someone else comes in searching!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open BlackBerry_App_Descriptor
2. In Packaging tag, set the value of OutputFileName to whatever you want
3. Rebuild

And if you want to change the title appearing to the user under app icon, change the value of Title in General tag.

If you are using Eclipse, opening BlackBerry_App_Descriptor, you may find a tab called Build to change COD & ALX names via a graphical UI which has the same impact to the file and also a tab called Application where you can change the title.